# How do I create another instance of a .NET program within one instance by code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I need to be able to create another brand new instance of a program on a button click while keeping the existing instance.

```
this.ShowDialog(new Form1());
```

The above statement causes the current form to be the owner of the new form and I need the second instance to be independent of the existing instance.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: why dont u try process.start?

Comment: are you trying to create a new instance of a **Program** or of a **Form**?

Comment: actually it is the other way around - newly created form1 becomes the owner of the current form. It does not happen, however, since the new instance is not made visible.

Comment: then start a new process as per [Desolator's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11332760/1106367)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expound on Desolator's answer here is a simplistic example you can try a Form and a Button:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
        p.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use instead `new Form1().Show();`, but when your current instances exists, the other one will exit too. So, to be fully independent, it is better to use [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) which starts your program exactly as if one double clicks it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(new Form1()).Show();

(new Form1()).Show();
```