# Running another instance of an application from one instance.

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Just like `Sticky Notes` in `Windows 7`, I want to create a `mainForm` which adds a new Form whenever the user clicks on a `Button` say `btnAdd`. This new Form should have all the properties of `mainForm`.

I have tried:

```
private void btnAdd_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainForm newForm=new mainForm();
    newForm.show();
}
```

But even though this is creating a form similar to `mainForm`, it closes when we close the `mainForm`.

Comment: I think you should be using .show() method instead of .showDialog().
Even then I think it would close when you closed the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for...

[Answer from another thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332731/how-do-i-create-another-instance-of-a-net-program-within-one-instance-by-code)

Copied :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
    p.Start();
}
```